# Left Join table with first match historically

Tags: postgresql, join, table

[image: Table A]

[image: Table B]

[image]

What I want to accomplish is to join TableB to TableA where TableA.date <= TableB.date, but only the the value with the nearest max date to Table.B.date. Currently, what I get is all the previous value like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

postgres version: PostgreSQL 9.2.24

Scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE public.table_a (
    id serial8 NOT NULL,
    value text NULL,
    "date" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);

INSERT INTO public.table_a
(value, "date")
VALUES
('Value 1', '2020-01-29'::date),
('Value 2', '2020-02-01'::date),
('Value 3', '2020-02-12'::date);


CREATE TABLE public.table_b (
    id serial8 NOT NULL,
    value text NULL,
    "date" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);

INSERT INTO public.table_b
(value, "date")
VALUES
('Task A', '2020-02-05'::date),
('Task B', '2020-02-15'::date);
```

Comment: @akina I already added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT table_a.value value_a, 
                     table_b.value value_b, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY table_b.value ORDER BY table_a."date" DESC) rn 
              FROM table_a
              JOIN table_b ON table_a."date" <= table_b."date")
SELECT value_b, value_a
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=425c933d86e7a7753664adcad9fc7e2b)

Check does this is applicable to your server version.

Comment: Thanks! it works!!!!